# angular ui.router state.go('statename') not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is the angular.ui.router definition

```
app.config([
  '$stateProvider',
  '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
      $stateProvider.state('/login',{
          url: "/",
          controller: 'Login',
          templateUrl: 'login.html'
      })
      .state('/useractivities',{
          url: "/activities",
          controller: 'activitiesController',
          templateUrl: 'useractivities.html'
      })
  }
]);
```

In the login controller I am executing

```
$state.go('useractivities', {});
```

This gives an error "Could not resolve 'useractivities' from state '/'"

I have tried a few things like

```
$location.url('useractivities')
```

but no luck, can anyone tell me whats going wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The issue here is that `to` param of the `$state.go()` call must be existing state **name**. And the `'activities'` is not existing name... it is the *`'/activities'`*

I would firstly suggest to use different state naming:

```
$stateProvider
  // instead of this
  // .state('/',{
  // let's use this state name      
  .state('login',{          // this is a STATE Name
      url: "/",
      controller: 'Login',
      templateUrl: 'login.html'
  })
  // instead of this
  // .state('/activities',{
  // use this
  .state('activities',{      // this is a STATE Name
      url: "/activities",
      controller: 'activitiesController',
      templateUrl: 'useractivities.html'
  })
```

And then this will work

```
$state.go('activities', {}); // we use STATE Name here
$state.go('login', {});      // also state name...
```

Check here for more details:

#### [$state.go(to [, toParams] [, options])](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options)

> **`to`**
>
> String Absolute State Name or Relative State Path
>
> The name of the state that will be transitioned to or a relative state path. If the path starts with ^ or . then it is relative, otherwise it is absolute.
>
> Some examples:

```
$state.go('contact.detail') will go to the 'contact.detail' state
$state.go('^') will go to a parent state.
$state.go('^.sibling') will go to a sibling state.
$state.go('.child.grandchild') will go to a grandchild state.
```

Comment: Just saw it I am using '/' in state name. Thanks Radim

Comment: Great to see that you make it! The `UI-Router` is amazing lib ;)

Answer (score 2):

This issue can also occur if you try to use a "." in your state name. E.g.,

```
$stateProvider.state("Activities.Details", { url: ... })
...
$state.go("Activities.Details");
```

If you use a "_" or some other non-reserved character, it will work fine.

```
$stateProvider.state("Activities_Details", { url: ... })
...
$state.go("Activities_Details");
```

Comment: Do note that a dot notation '.' represents a child state of the state name preceded before the dot. So, if the you're trying to go to `go.sub`, sub is supposed to be the child state of state 'go'. So, if you haven't defined sub as child of 'go', it won't work.